# Variable name made of a variable value

Tags: javascript

How can i use a variable value to name a variable?

```
var xyz = "test";   
var (xyz) = "abc";
alert (test);
```

Comment: did some research but didnt find a straightforward answer...

Comment: I can sort of see situations it might be useful, but I can only imagine that if it was possible (it's not, outside of objects or `eval()`) it'd lead to a world of debugging-pain.

Comment: i have a object.
and within it  it uses some html id's.
an because i wil have more than one instances of this object, i would like them to be different for each instance...

Comment: @Nomistake, you should create a map of the divs by ID, instead of creating variables with dynamic names

Comment: @Tyler I think you're saying you hate it but that this does not seem to warrant dynamic variable names, right? Specially globals.

Comment: @JuanMendes, can you give a direction how to do this? like a link or something... maps would be new to me...

Comment: I voted up Nil's answer, it's doing what I suggested http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678470/variable-name-made-of-a-variable-value#answer-12678506

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript dynamic variable name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/javascript-dynamic-variable-name)

Answer (score 5):

If you put them in an object, you could do this instead:

```
var Container = {};
var xyz = "test";
Container[xyz] = "abc";
alert(Container['test']);
```

Answer (score 2):

A variable name can not be the result of an expression unless you use `eval`, which you don't want to do, or unless it's a global variable.

If you need dynamic naming, you should use an object, and name its properties dynamically. This is also how globals can be dynamically created.

```
var xyz = "test";

//global

window[xyz] = "abc";

alert(test);    // "abc"

// object property

var myData = {};
myData[xyz] = "abc";

alert(myData.test);    // "abc"
```

Answer (score 0):

eval does this:

```
xyz = "test";
eval(xyz+"=123");
alert(test); // gives 123
```

I am sure many say NO to eval. But, this does it.

Answer (score 0):

Without using eval or with, something like this is not possible, and these methods are not recommended for various reasons.

However, you can use a variable as a key for an object property:

```
var key = 'somestring';
var obj = {};

obj[key] = 'another value';
```

While setting properties on the global object (window in browsers) will do what you ask, I **strongly** recommend against writing business-logic code directly in global scope, **especially** with dynamic variable names. The potential for random name-collision bugs is too severe.

Answer (score 0):

If it is global scope

```
var xyz = "test";   
window[xyz] = "abc";
alert (test);
```

Better to use an object

```
var myObject = {};
var xyz = "test";   
myObject [xyz] = "abc";
alert (myObject.test);
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/s69XC/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var xyz = "test";   
eval ( xyz + "= 'abc';");
alert (test);
```